# What's the demographic that mainly uses this site?

Tags: discussion

I am beginning to become frustrated with this exchange, as it seems that I am never able to have a question answered.

Based on other questions from other users, it seems as if the demographic is a little less advanced than I can personally find useful.

I'd like to know if there are other S/C professionals on board here, and if so, how many of us are there?

Comment: Just curious if you think there is another site or resource out there that you think is doing things better? I'd just be interested in seeing "the competition", as it were.

Comment: @EricKaufman unfortunately the ecosystem regarding sports and exercise science isn't very tech savvy. Currently solid resources include TNation and StrengthCoach.com.  With T Nation one has to consider the source, and with SC, you actually have to pay. I love the structure here, but it seems like there's only a handful of qualified or experienced professionals on this exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I went and took a look at the questions you have asked, and considered the answers and the comments:

1. [Resistance/running](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/any-input-on-fixing-running-form-with-resistance-training) - I left a comment that you later added as the answer. I didn't flesh it as a full answer as I was not 100% sure of my stance.
2. [Cuing compendium](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/20936/what-resources-are-recommended-to-learn-more-about-cuing-specifically) - I didn't know of a resource. I should have left a comment noting that I didn't know of one, that most of the cues I used changed from individual to individual. (Just as a note, searching on fitness cuing brings up your question as the 3rd google hit). I think that in the long run, cues that you use will vary from person to person depending on their learning style and methods. You may build up a compendium of your own for each learning style, but I don't think it's been a universal thing yet, because it is so scatter shot in approach from client to client.
3. [Anabolic mets](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/metabolic-equations-for-anaroebic-exercise) - Again, I didn't know of a resource, but left a comment elaborating why I didn't think you would find anything.
4. [Overtrained back](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/22140/what-can-be-the-negative-effects-associated-with-an-overtrained-overdeveloped-b) - Missed this one.
5. [Shoulder presses](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/21067/will-doing-a-large-amount-of-shoulder-presses-interspersed-throughout-the-day-im) - Didn't think I could improve on the answer.
6. [Split routines](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19497/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-shorter-bouts-of-resistance-training) - Missed this one as well.

FWIW, I don't have any current certifications, but my first degree way back in the day (1991) was in exercise kinesiology, and I've kept as current as someone who doesn't make their living from it can.

Part of the problem is what the Health SE site is about to face, and what we discussed during private beta - If you want the experts to come, you need to ask expert level questions. If it goes unanswered, share the links among greater communities.

For the most part, I see a lot of very beginner questions or questions that ignore site scope, and a lot of "bro science" answers. I agree, that there is a lack of expertise out there. That is one reason that I would encourage you to stay and participate, as your questions will be of the type that attract expert users.